# How to get Nginx Proxy caching to work with dynamic content

Tags: caching, joomla, nginx, proxy

So this is giving me a headache and perhaps someone has already masterd it.I have a Joomla 2.5 site with allot of dynamic content but also static.

This is my current config. But i cant get it to understand when the site outputs a session cookie i don't want it to cache it. So basically (If unregistered/ Not logged in, Deliever cached content.)

```
proxy_cache_path C:/Users/root/Desktop/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my-cache:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
proxy_temp_path C:/Users/root/Desktop/nginx/temp/proxy_temp;

server {
listen   80;
listen   [::]:80;

server_name  domain.com

root   c:/server/websites/ps/public_www;
index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

location / {
root   c:/server/websites/ps/public_www;

if ($cookie_session) { set $do_not_cache 1; }
if ($request_method = 'POST') { set $do_not_cache 1; }
if ($request_uri ~* "administrator") { set $do_not_cache 1; }

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000;

# Define which cache to use
proxy_cache my-cache;
# Define which responses to cache and for how long
proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
proxy_cache_valid  404      5m;
# Don't cache if our headers (or cookie) are present
proxy_no_cache $do_not_cache;
# Ignore the standard no-cache headers - these will still be sent to the browser
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
# Don't send our custom header to the browser
proxy_hide_header X-Dont-Cache-Me;
# This next line is important if we're planning on caching for more than one site on the server
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$host$request_uri";
proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
```

If anyone can help would be very greatfull it is very annoying that it caches cookies (including when i am logged in) and would deliever it to other people.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).